# Stored Procedure for insert/update and select results in error multi-part identifier could not be found

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create the StoredProcedure which Insert/Updates the table also select the record that was inserted or updated

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InserUpadte] 
@account_TT AS account_TT READONLY

 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 MERGE dbo.[clarity_Account] prj
 USING @account_TT tt
 ON prj.AccountID = tt.AccountID
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prj.CounterSeq = prj.CounterSeq+1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AccountID,CounterSeq)
 VALUES (tt.AccountID, 1);

 select * from dbo.[clarity_Account] where AccountID = tt.AccountID;

 COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 END;
```

Here account_TT is the Table Type with AccountID nvarchar(50). Here I get error in the

```
  select * from dbo.[clarity_Account] where AccountID = tt.AccountID;
```

`Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_InserUpadte, Line 28
The multi-part identifier "tt.AccountID" could not be bound.`

Comment: `tt` alias doesn't exist in your query.  It only applies to the query it was declared in (your `MERGE` statement).

Comment: Do I have to again declare them ?

Comment: No, you just need to do a `JOIN` to your table variable in your query.

Comment: The "USING @account_TT tt" "tt" alias exists only for the MERGE statement.  You need to rejoin that custom-data-type for the SELECT query.  Basically, the scope of an alias is only for one statement.

Comment: Temp table ? Prj?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the alias of the table used in the `MERGE` statement in your second query, where it isn't known.  You just need to do a `JOIN` to your table variable:

```
 Select  CA.*
 From    dbo.[clarity_Account]  CA
 Join    @account_TT            TT  On  CA.AccountID = TT.AccountID;
```